# Is there a way to use ionicons without the <script> tag?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, svelte, sveltekit

At my company the designer decided to use [ionicons](https://ionic.io/ionicons) but the [docs](https://ionic.io/ionicons/usage) only specify this way of using them without Ionic:

> Place the following `<script>` near the end of your page, right before the closing `</body>` tag, to enable them.

```html
<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
<script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
```

> To use a built-in icon from the Ionicons package, populate the name attribute on the ion-icon component:

```html
<ion-icon name="heart"></ion-icon>
```

But by doing this, a `GET` request needs to be made to the CDN (unpkg.com). This makes the icons "flash" and shift the UI whilst loading.

**Is there a way to use the [NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionicons) and import it into my project? This way the icons will load instantly without shifting my UI.**

I've tried the following in my svelte-kit project:

### First attempt

```html
<script>
  import "ionicons/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm";
</script>
```

This throws the following error in my terminal:

```bash
TypeError: u.querySelector is not a function
    at Module.q (/node_modules/.pnpm/ionicons@6.0.2/node_modules/ionicons/dist/ionicons/p-9857dedb.js:3:6277)
    at eval (/node_modules/.pnpm/ionicons@6.0.2/node_modules/ionicons/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js?v=642066af:4:162)
 ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1.
```

### Second attempt

```html
<script>
  import "ionicons/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js";
</script>
```

This throws this error:

```bash
ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Carlos Daniel\Documents\code\jequi-frontend\node_modules\.pnpm\ionicons@6.0.2\node_modules\ionicons\dist\ionicons\ionicons.js:130:9)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:190:29)
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:185:25)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:281:24)
```

### Third attempt

```html
<script>
  import { onMount } from "svelte";

  // no SSR
  onMount(async () => {
    await import("ionicons/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js");
  });
</script>
```

This throws this error in the browser's console:

```
GET http://localhost:3010/p-09cd4d8b.system.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Uncaught (in promise) Error: Error loading http://localhost:3010/p-09cd4d8b.system.js at HTMLScriptElement.<anonymous> (ionicons.js:107:2894)
```

### Fourth attempt

```html
<script>
  import { onMount } from "svelte";

  // no SSR
  onMount(async () => {
    await import("ionicons/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm");
  });
</script>
```

This throws this error in my browser's console:

```bash
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to construct 'URL': Invalid URL
    at ionicons.esm.js:1:109
    at ionicons.esm.js:1:134
```

and this one in my terminal:

```bash
344|  var J = (e2) => {
345|    const t2 = e2.o.replace(/-/g, "_"), n2 = e2.U, l2 = I.get(n2);
346|    return l2 ? l2[t2] : import(`./${n2}.entry.js`).then((e3) => (I.set(n2, e3), e3[t2]), G);
   |                                ^
347|  };
348|  var K = /* @__PURE__ */ new Map();
The above dynamic import cannot be analyzed by vite.
See https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/dynamic-import-vars#limitations for supported dynamic import formats. If this is intended to be left as-is, you can use the /* @vite-ignore */ comment inside the import() call to suppress this warning.
```

## Soooo....

**Any ideas on how to make this work?** I really don´t want to use a CDN because of the shifting in the UI while loading, and no I can´t just use another icon library since I´ve already tried to convince my boss into changing the lib but they simply won´t.

I'm also aware there are some [packages](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=ionicons%20svelte) that are built for svelte, but they are not official, and the way they work doesn't seem to be a good implementation. I've already used them in past projects and it's a pain handling all the imports.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried https://ionicframework.com/

Comment: Yes, but this is a non ionic project. They want me to use the ionicons without the Ionic framework.

Comment: Note that they won't load instantly anyway regardless of whether you're using a CDN or your server. The script would still need to do several fetches due to the way that icon pack is designed.

Answer (score 1):

The general approach for dealing with this is using the source vector files, usually SVG, and turn them into Svelte components via an automated script. This is fairly frictionless with SVGs because they can be used directly in Svelte components.

If you do not like the existing packages that do exactly this, like [`svelte-ionicons`](https://github.com/shinokada/svelte-ionicons), you might have to do it yourself.

You also could implement/use a custom loader for whatever build tool you are using to directly inline the SVGs or import them in your components.

(The SVGs are distributed with the package in `ionicons/dist/svg`)